# Extracting object array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6

I am trying to parse an object which contains arrays. I need the object where `language` is `"en"`,

```js
    "translations": [
        {"languageCode": "id","value": "Program Televisi"},
        {"languageCode": "ms","value": ""}, 
        {"languageCode": "ar","value": "تليفزيون"},
        {"languageCode": "en","value": "Television"}
    ]
},
"subgenre": {
    "id": 227,
    "translations": [
        {"languageCode": "id","value": "Sports"},
        {"languageCode": "ms","value": ""}, 
        {"languageCode": "ar","value": ""},
        {"languageCode": "en","value": "Sports"}
    ]
}
```

I don't want to do it this way :

```
translations_array.forEach(function (obj1, i) {
  if (obj1.languageCode === 'en') {
    return obj1.value.toString();
  }                        
});
```

Instead I'd rather something like fetching directly:

```
translations[].value[languageCode='en']
```

Comment: FYI nothing about this has anything to do with JSON. I've amended the question and title accordinly

Comment: ...and the better layout shows you've mised the id and key of that first array. Doesnt affect the answer.

Comment: @Jamiec: I assume you've found a better duplicate target?

Comment: @Cerbrus no, but I can tell you the one that was chosen was terrible and nothing to do with this question or its answer.

Comment: So, do a quick search to find a proper target, instead of opening this for more answers...

Comment: @Cerbrus I have and I am. Calm yourself. There is no harm in this getting other answers. And having your question closed with a pointless duplicate is just annoying for newer users

Comment: There is harm: We don't want to give users the idea it's okay to answer obvious duplicates. Those answers prevent the Roomba from doing its job. Just like the upvoted answer on here is not preventing this question from being auto-deleted.

Comment: btw, why is there a return value in `forEach`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Array.find :

```
let languageObj = translations.find( obj => obj.languageCode === 'en')
```

Comment: thanks very much , short and simple...